# How to set position second form depend on first form?

Tags: c#

I have Form1 and Form2 and a button in my project. When i click button Form2 will show. What is the command to set position of Form2 at center of form1?

Comment: are you aware of `MDI Forms `??

Comment: I don't use MDI Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the location when you open it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f2.Load += delegate(object s2, EventArgs e2)
        {
            f2.Location = new Point(this.Bounds.Location.X + this.Bounds.Width / 2 - f2.Width / 2,
                this.Bounds.Location.Y + this.Bounds.Height / 2 - f2.Height / 2);
        };
        f2.Show();
    }
```

**The key here is setting the [StartPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) to manual.**

On my system, setting `StartPosition` to `CenterParent` and using `Show(this)` doesn't center on the "owner".  Maybe something is broken on my system...it's always been like that for me.

Comment: This is not correct, the Bounds property is meaningless until the Load event fires.   Only then can you know the true size of the window, the user preferences and DPI rescaling are applied by then.  One of the very few reasons to ever actually use the Load event.

Comment: @HansPassant...the Bounds property is being accessed for the **already open Form1** via `this` in a Button click handler.  I'm not accessing Bounds for Form2...just using `f2.Width` and `f2.Height`, which should be the designed width/height of the form...?

Comment: Sure, I fumbled that comment, it is f2.Width/Height that is the problem.  It will not be the design size at runtime.  User overrides are the size of the caption buttons and font, DPI rescaling ensures they are *drastically* different from the design size.  The workaround is simple, use the Load event.

Comment: Why would you do it manually when there is already a CenterParent property?

Comment: @ArthurRey, CenterParent works nicely with ShowDialog(), but not with Show()...or am I missing something?

Comment: `Show(this)` with `CenterParent` doesn't work on my system.  =/

Answer (score 1):

Set the forms StartPosition property to CenterParent.  That way it will always pop up in the center.

Comment: It only center of screen but i want form2 center of form1

Comment: Sorry. Had copied from something. Center parent is what you want.

Comment: That's what you want to use, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use an instance of the 2nd form.  See example of my 2 form project

Form 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2 = new Form2(this);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
            string  results = form2.GetData();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1;
        public Form2(Form1 nform1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing +=  new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
            form1 = nform1;
            form1.Hide();
        }
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //stops form from closing
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: See responses from other postings.

Comment: Downvoted because there is absolutely nothing related to position in your answer.

Comment: Authur :  My response was that you need to use and instance of the class and my example shows exactly that.  I didn't show exactly how to pass the parameter of setting the position, but it is similar to the code posted.  All other solutions were after mine using an instance of the form class.

Comment: @jdweng OP already knows how to instanciate the form, he wants to know how to center it.

Comment: Are you sure OP know how to instanciate?

Comment: @jdweng "What is the command to set position of Form2 at center of form1?" Doesn't say that he needs to learn how to instanciate new form.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the OP knows how to instantiate?  Read the original posting again.